# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report - May 2019

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, announcement

## Welcome to the 20th edition of the monthly Ask Different Most Active Contributors Report.

Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback in the comments.

[image: TITLE: REPORT TITLE]

### Report for May 2019

This report includes the following sections:

1. Overall Most Active Contributors Award
2. Monthly Reputation Leader Board
3. Most Active Editors Award
4. Most Active Voters Award
5. Most Active Close Vote Reviewers
6. Most Active First Post Reviewers
7. Most Active Late Answer Reviewers
8. Most Active Low-Quality Post Reviewers
9. Most Active Reopen Post Reviewers
10. Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award
11. Highest Voted Questions Award
12. Highest Voted Answers Award
13. Most Viewed Questions Award
14. Ranked 1st Summary List
15. Moderators Activity Summary

---

[image: TITLE: OVERALL MOST ACIVE CONTRIBUTORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema              460
2   nohillside                200
3   jksoegaard                140
4   Monomeeth                 130
5   grg                       110
```

**Note:** This is an overall ranking based on all activities. Maximum possible score = 1,150.

---

[image: TITLE: MONTHLY REPUTATION LEADER BOARD]

[image]
A total of 1,574<sup>*</sup> users earned reputation during the month. You can view the full list [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/118/month/apple/2019-05-01).<sup>1</sup>

<sup>* This figure is much lower than usual due to an event that resulted in the loss of reputation for 100s of users. See [Do my eyes deceive me? Lots of people lost a lot of reputation today](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3579/do-my-eyes-deceive-me-lots-of-people-lost-a-lot-of-reputation-today) for more info.</sup>

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE EDITORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  EDITS
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema              220
2   bmike                      83
3   IconDaemon                 55
4   nohillside                 37
5   Edd Growl                  28
```

A big thank you to all 18 users who edited questions or answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE VOTERS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  VOTES
---------------------------------------
1   PeterJ                  1,296
2   bmike                     237
3   Monomeeth                 193
4   Nimesh Neema              187
5   lhf                       129
```

A big thank you to all 57 users who voted on questions or answers this month!<sup>2</sup>

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE CLOSE VOTE REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   nohillside                 75
2   Nimesh Neema               37
3   Monomeeth                  17
4   Allan                      15
5   Glorfindel                 14
```

A big thank you to all 18 users who reviewed Close Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE FIRST POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema              259
2   Greenonline               245
3   Monomeeth                  95
4   Wilfred Smith              71
5   fsb                        33
```

A big thank you to all 23 users who reviewed First Posts this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE LATE ANSWERS REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema               76
2   Greenonline                69
3   Tetsujin                   45
4   fsb                        21
5   Wilfred Smith              17
```

A big thank you to all 13 users who reviewed Late Answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE LOW-QUALITY POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema               26
2   Tetsujin                   15
3   Glorfindel, Allan          12
4   nohillside, abc            10
5   Monomeeth, Steve Chambers   8
```

A big thank you to all 15 users who reviewed Low-Quality Posts this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE REOPEN POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema               16
2   nohillside                 15
3   Tetsujin                   10
4   Allan                       9
5   fsb                         5
```

A big thank you to all 13 users who reviewed Reopen Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE SUGGESTED EDIT REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema               59
2   nohillside                 50
3   Monomeeth                  24
4   Glorfindel                 22
5   fsb                        15
```

A big thank you to all 38 users who reviewed Suggested Edits this month!

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [What replaces x86 intrinsics for C when Apple ditches Intel CPUs for their own chips?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359644/what-replaces-x86-intrinsics-for-c-when-apple-ditches-intel-cpus-for-their-own-c)

   - Posted by: Nanashi No Gombe
   - Votes: **17**
2. [Internet speed getting slower over time on MBP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359723/internet-speed-getting-slower-over-time-on-mbp)

   - Posted by: jojek
   - Votes: **14**
3. [Send iMessage from Firefox](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359141/send-imessage-from-firefox)

   - Posted by: gatorback
   - Votes: **8**
4. [Can't add items to iTunes library](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/360512/cant-add-items-to-itunes-library)

   - Posted by: Richard Kranendonk
   - Votes: **7**
5. [How to create an executable file for an AppleScript?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/360208/how-to-create-an-executable-file-for-an-applescript)

   - Posted by: mmoomocow
   - Votes: **7**

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED ANSWER AWARD]

1. [What replaces x86 intrinsics for C when Apple ditches Intel CPUs for their own chips?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/359647/168832)

   - Posted by: jksoegaard
   - Votes: **20**
2. [How to create an executable file for an AppleScript?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/360209/168832)

   - Posted by: grg
   - Votes: **15**
3. [Removing all characters except digits from clipboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/359736/168832)

   - Posted by: nohillside
   - Votes: **13**
4. [Newly installed programs always appear with external drives in Finder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/359974/168832)

   - Posted by: benwiggy
   - Votes: **12**
5. [Can't add items to iTunes library](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/360586/168832)

   - Posted by: Alex Z.
   - Votes: **11**

---

[image: TITLE: MOST VIEWED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [What replaces x86 intrinsics for C when Apple ditches Intel CPUs for their own chips?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359644/what-replaces-x86-intrinsics-for-c-when-apple-ditches-intel-cpus-for-their-own-c)

   - Posted by: Nanashi No Gombe
   - Votes: **3,582**
2. [How does noise-cancellation work in Mac laptops?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359905/how-does-noise-cancellation-work-in-mac-laptops)

   - Posted by: Antonio23249
   - Views: **1,235**
3. [AirPods blinking orange as long as they are both in the case, one of the pods don’t work](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359588/airpods-blinking-orange-as-long-as-they-are-both-in-the-case-one-of-the-pods-do)

   - Posted by: C-flow
   - Views: **1,080**
4. [Can't add items to iTunes library](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/360512/cant-add-items-to-itunes-library)

   - Posted by: Richard Kranendonk
   - Votes: **995**
5. [Send iMessage from Firefox](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359141/send-imessage-from-firefox)

   - Posted by: gatorback
   - Votes: **862**

---

[image: TITLE: RANKED 1st SUMMARY LIST]

**1.    Overall Most Active Contributors Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**2.    Monthly Reputation Leader Board**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**3.    Most Active Editors Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**4.    Most Active Voters Award**

- [PeterJ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/83841/peterj)

**5.    Most Active Close Vote Reviewers Award**

- [nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/nohillside)

**6.    Most Active First Post Reviewers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**7.    Most Active Late Answer Reviewers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**8.    Most Active Low-Quality Post Reviewers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**9.    Most Active Reopen Post Reviewers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**10.   Most Active Suggested Edit Reviewers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**11.   Highest Voted Questions Award**

- [Nanashi No Gombe](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/300463/nanashi-no-gombe)

**12.   Highest Voted Answers Award**

- [jksoegaard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/77912/jksoegaard)

**13.   Most Viewed Questions Award**

- [Nanashi No Gombe](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/300463/nanashi-no-gombe)

---

[image: TITLE: MODERATORS ACTIVITY SUMMARY]

In May our [Moderators](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) actioned **190 flags** with an average handling time of **39 minutes**. In summary, we also:

- deleted 284 comments
- deleted 89 posts
- closed 159 posts
- edited 205 posts
- created 71 posts
- created 480 comments

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering their time to make this site so great. We appreciate the contributions made by all users, not just those listed in this report!

Keep up the great work! :)

---

<sup>**1.** Due to the possibility of profile changes over time, this link may not reflect the screenshot above.</sup>

<sup>**2.** Only users who have voted over 10 times in the period are counted in this metric.</sup>